# Reference request: Location of maximum of Laplacian eigenfunction

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, eigenfunctions

Background: Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded convex domain. By classical results, the (signed) Laplacian $-\Delta$ on $U$ with zero boundary conditions admits $L^2(U)$-orthonormal eigenfunctions $\{\phi_n:\overline{U}\to\mathbb{R}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, corresponding to positive eigenvalues listed in increasing order. $\phi_1$ is called the principal Dirichlet Laplacian eigenfunction, and is everywhere positive on $U$. Moreover, results of Brascamp-Lieb imply that $\phi$ is log-concave, so that $\phi$ achieves its maximum value at some unique $x_U\in U$.

Question: I am looking for a reference to validate or disprove the following claim: The point $x_U$ achieves the inradius $\text{inrad}(U)=\max_{x\in U}\text{dist}(x,\partial U)$ of $U$. (Note that, however, the inradius need not be achieved at a unique point. For example, a long rectangle contains an entire line segment achieving the inradius.)

Comment: Best bet is to just try it out (e.g. numerically) on simple shapes like triangles or irregular polygons. Statements like this are almost certainly false, but you are unlikely to find references with explicit counterexamples. I do recall some papers of David Jerison on the second eigenfunction in this spirit (I think he proves estimates sort of by comparison) that you could look through.

Comment: @user378654 Do you mind elaborating on why you think "statements like this are almost certainly false"?

Comment: Intuition, tempered by experience. Any statement like the one in your question has probability 0 of being true, in the sense that you chose an arbitrary set center and an arbitrary solution to a PDE. The location of the maximum of a solution to a PDE depends nontrivially on the PDE, so if I look at a large number of PDE that behave similarly to yours ($\Delta u = f(u)$ for suitable $f$, say), for a generic domain and generic PDE I expect the points to not coincide. Maybe you feel that your particular choices are special, but the burden is on you to argue why.